# C# Get Class Object List from ViewModel

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I have data viewModel with two class object.

```
 public class StudentViewModel
{
    public PeopleEntity People { get; set; }
    public PeopleUnitEntity PeopleUnit { get; set; }
}
```

In following code I get values for both PeopleEntity and PeopleUnitEntity

```
IList<StudentViewModel> _stv = _StudentServicesObject.GetStudentByPersonCode(PersonCode);
```

I want to store only People List in new PeopleEntity Object, how can I do that???

I tried as following but it doesn't work for me

```
 IList<PeopleEntity> _People = _StudentServicesObject.GetStudentByPersonCode(PersonCode).Select(pl => new PeopleEntity { People = pl });
```

Error

[image]

Comment: Why not .ToList()

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
IList<PeopleEntity> _People = _StudentServicesObject.GetStudentByPersonCode(PersonCode).Select(pl => pl.People).ToList();
```

???

Comment: yes I tried, refer to error in my question update with screenshot

Comment: Add .ToList() to the end.

Comment: Or change the definition of _stv to be IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Where returns an IEnumerable, not an IList so you need to either make _stv an IEnumerable or convert the result into a List.

Comment: Sorry when I was providing this answer there where no answers given in the comments !